# PoE system with Active Clamp Forward

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, texas-instruments, synchronous, poe

Does anyone know if choose the Active clamp forward as the topology in PoE system,
according to this figure which from [TI Design document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaf59/slvaf59.pdf?ts=1626186506397&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), What's the function of C39. I do not understand why need to put the capacitor in there, is this DC block capacitor? can someone explain it to me?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you drive a P-channel, you need a negative bias to turn it on when the source is ground-referenced. The diode clamps on the positive excursion and, via the capacitor, shifts the 12-V drive voltage below ground, effectively turning the P-channel on. See the below waveform:

[image]

The best is to run small sims like in the above to test particular sections of this converter. You can freely use one of the 60+ SIMPLIS templates that I posted [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) as they work with the demo version. If you want to read more on the ACF, I published this [article](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1906/articles/H2PToday1906_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) in [How2Power](https://www.how2power.com/newsletters/) in 2019 and it covers loop compensation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Do you know how to calculate this capacitor value? because the design guide doesn't teach how to calculate.

Your article is great.